# Flutter ListView changing values

Tags: list, flutter, listview, boolean, audio-player

I have a question:
I have a ListView.builder in Flutter with Songs and every Song item has a Play Button on the left. So I click the play button the Icon changes and the song gets played.
When I click another song in the list how can I set the Icon to stop from the previous song? Like in this Video:

https://youtu.be/zAXN1QQMM-4

So just setting the icon/bool of the previous icon to false and the new one to true.

Comment: Please provide your code what you achieved so far

Comment: Sorry I have nothing valuable only the list view builder with the bool values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

You should create a state variable, in this case `_index`. This value holds the index of the item that is currently being played. In the `builder` method of the `ListView` widget you can check if it's index is the same as the state's index.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: App()));

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  /// The song that is currently selected.
  int? _index;

  void _updateSelected(int index) => setState(() => _index = index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 10,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        // Check whether the index is the selected index.
        final _isSelected = index == _index;

        return ListTile(
          title: Text('Song title'),
          // Change the icon based on `isSelected`.
          leading: Icon(_isSelected ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow),
          // Call the method when the tile is tapped.
          onTap: () => _updateSelected(index),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```